# Clojure: What is the default server for the luminus framework?

Tags: http, clojure, luminus

As of right now (2018) what is the http/tcp server used when you set up a luminus template project with its default setting?

I'm reading that luminus uses immutant, however, immutant is a collection of other stuff. and I've also read that the underlying server used in immutant is undertow.

Am I correct in assuming that the default server is undertow? If so, how does the default set up perform with respect to non-blocking IO? Does this server afford a non-blocking event loop architecture like nginx/nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Immutant uses Undertow as its web server.

Undertow uses non-blocking IO threads (typically one per CPU core) and also manages a pool of worker threads. To quote their [documentation](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/#management-of-io-and-worker-threads):

> The XNIO worker manages both the IO threads, and a thread pool that
>   can be used for blocking tasks. In general non-blocking handlers will
>   run from withing an IO thread, while blocking tasks such as Servlet
>   invocations will be dispatched to the worker thread pool.
>
> IO threads run in a loop. This loop does three things:
>
> - Run any tasks that have been scheduled for execution by the IO thread
> - Run any scheduled tasks that that have hit their timeout
> - Call Selector.select(), and then invoke any callbacks for selected
>     keys

The obvious difference between this architecture and a node architecture is the separation of the pool of worker threads, which are allowed to block.

I'm afraid I can't speak to comparing actual *performance*, which would be use-case specific.

Answer (score 2):

As of mid-2019, the default HTTP server is **Jetty** through the `luminus-jetty` package. This is encoded here, with other supported servers named after the default:

```
(set-feature "+jetty" #{"+aleph" "+http-kit" "+immutant" "+war"})
```

Source: [Luminus](https://github.com/luminus-framework/luminus-template/blob/962be922c47d5c0e573cb5fd79c3ca697e8c6ad3/src/leiningen/new/luminus.clj).

Answer (score 2):

As of mid-2020 Liminus has switched to [ring-undertow](https://github.com/luminus-framework/luminus-template#alternative-servers) as a default server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it uses immutant by default, but you can choose [alternative servers](https://github.com/luminus-framework/luminus-template#alternative-servers).